# Showing that the spectrum is $\{0\}$ for an $l^2$ operator.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, inequality, convergence-divergence

Let $T(x_1,x_2,\dots)=(0,\frac{x_1}{2}, \frac{x_2}{4},\dots, \frac{x_n}{2^n},\dots)$. I'm trying to show that $\sigma(T) = \{0\}.$ It's easy to show that $0\in \sigma(T)$, so I only need to show that the spectral radius is $0$. I'm having an issue getting a bound on $||T^n||$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think it'll follow from this: [Show that the spectrum of an operator on $l^2$ is {0}.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1414306/show-that-the-spectrum-of-an-operator-on-ell2-mathbbn-is-0?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $x=(x_1,...,x_n,...) $ such that $\|x\|=1$ and compute $T^n (x)=(0,0...,0,\frac{x_1}{2^{1+2+...+n}},\frac{x_2}{2^{2+3+...+(n+1)}},...) $. Now try to estimate $\|T^n\|$.

Comment: I computed $T^n(x)= (0,0,0,\dots, \frac{x_1}{2^\frac{n(n+1)}{2}},\dots)$. I don't know how to obtain manageable forms for the other terms.

Comment: Your form of $T^n(x)$ is not correct.

Comment: @Ant : Can you see that all the other coefficients are no larger than the first non-zero one in $T^n(x)$? If you can, then that estimate is enough to give you $\|T^n(x)\| \le 2^{-n(n+1)/2}\|x\|$.

Comment: @CheeHan : Explain why you think it is wrong.

Comment: @TrialAndError: Yes, it should follow from Holder's. Thank you very much!

Comment: @CheeHan: It looks okay to me. I used a closed form for 1+2+3+...+n.

Comment: @Ant : I think I would mark this an answer.

Comment: @Ant : And Holder is not needed because the first constant in the list is the smallest, so that's a bound.

Comment: @Ant Sorry, I was referring to Soma's initial answer. I got exactly what you had for $T^n(x)$!